# How to create a database using SQL Scripts?

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL script and I need to create a database in other server using this SQL scripts in SQL server 2016. Is it possible and can you explain me the steps to do it?

Comment: You would script the create database statement. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/create-a-database Have you even tried??

Comment: okay, I have a script and run on 1 server and when I want to use it on other server, where is the connection string and where can I find it

Comment: Connection string??? You don't put connection strings in a script. You need to connect to the other server and run your script.

Answer (score 0):

Right click database on the old server instance, `Script Database as`, then `Create to`, execute the script on the new server instance after changing the `Connection`

Comment: Where do I find the Connection string

Comment: where to change the connection string?